# Securing a Cassandra Cluster

Tags: security, clustering, encryption, ssl, cassandra

We've managed to set up a Cassandra 2.2.6 cluster of two physical nodes (nodetool sees both of them, so I'm quite certain the cluster is indeed active). My steps to create the cluster were (this applies to both machines):

- Empty `listen_address` and `rpc_address`.
- Define a `cluster_name`.
- Define both machines as `seeds`.
- Open ports 9042, 7000 and 7001 for external communication.

Now I want to secure access to the cluster in all forms:

- define a different database user with a new password
- encrypt communication bet ween clients and the cluster including client verification
- encrypt communication between the nodes including verification

What is the best order of steps and correct way to achieve this? I wanted to start with defining a different user, but cqlsh refuses to connect after enforcing user/password authentication:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

This happens when I run the command on either of the two machines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.